# Any free service or API will provide Geo coordinates (lat and long)?

Tags: c#, geolocation

I am searching for web service or API for Geo coordinates (lat and long) for free. If I pass city/State or country get lat and long values. IF you guys have any idea please share with me.

Answer (score 2):

The [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) is free, but is limited to 2,500 requests per day; while the business version is limited to 100,000 requests per day.